Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'sprocket' before initialization
I am currently working on an app and have run into the following error,

Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'sprocket' before initialization

This example below demonstrates the layering I currently have in my app.  What am I doing incorrect here?
../sprocket/sprocket.js
export const makeSprocket = ({
    sprocketRepository
}) => {
    const addSprocket = async (sprocket) => {
        return await sprocketRepository.create(sprocket);
    }

    const findSprocket = async (id) => {
        return await sprocketRepository.retrieve(id);
    }

    return {
        addSprocket,
        findSprocket
    }
}

../sprocket/index.js
import {makeSprocket} from './sprocket.js';
import {sprocketRepository} from '../repository/index.js';

const sprocket = makeSprocket({sprocketRepository});

export {
    sprocket
}

../sprocket/use-cases/fullfillorder.js
makeFullfillOrder({sprocketRepository, cogRepository, sprocket, cog}) => {
    const fulfill = (order) => {
        //there would be business rules here that require the dependencies listed above
    }

    return {
        fulfill
    }
}

../sprocket/use-cases/index.js
import {makeFulfillOrder} from '../index.js';
import {sprocket} from '../../cog/index.js';
import {cog} from '../../cog/index.js';
import {sprocketRepository} from '../../repository/index.js';
import {cogRepository} from '../../repository/index.js';

//**This is where the error seems to occur**
const fulfillOrder = makeFulfillOrder({sprocketRepository, cogRepository, sprocket, cog})

export {
    fulfillOrder
}

../mainapp/component/controllers/index.js
import {fulfillOrder} from 'lib/components/sprocket/use-cases/index.js';
export const saveSprocket = await (req,res) => {
    await fulfillOrder.fulfill(req.body);
        ...
}


At what point would it be initialized?
How can I ensure it gets initialized before it is accessed if I am importing from the module that is responsible for initializing it?


This typically is a circular dependency problem. Does ../repository/index.js somehow import ../sprocket/index.js again?

I did not see that.  Could this be a timing issue?  In this scenario, at what point is the sprocket variable created?    If I set a breakpoint where the sprocket variable is created I am not seeing that hit before the await sprocket.addSprocket line is reached.  How can I ensure the initialization occurs first?

No, import and module evaluation order is determinstic and depends on your entry point in the module graph.

As a debug step, using a pencil, write all the path/file names on one page, then draw an arrow when one imports another.  Look for cycles.

Found it.  Circular dependency.  Looking for a fix.  Thank you guys.
